# React Native - Animated.spring blinks when reverting the animation

Tags: javascript, android, animation, react-native

In my react native app I'm trying to create a drawer. When I click a button it should open, and that works perfectly fine, the problem is when I close it. When I click the close button the animation blinks, kind of like opening and closing for 2-3 times before it definitely closes.

This is how I'm doing it

```js
export default class Drawer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            height: new Animated.Value(0)
        }
    }

    showContent = () => {
        Animated.spring(this.state.height, {toValue:130}).start();
    }

    hideContent = () => {
        Animated.spring(this.state.height, {toValue:0}).start();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight 
                    onPress={this.showContent}
                    underlayColor="transparent"
                >
                    <Text>Show</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                <TouchableHighlight 
                    onPress={this.hideContent}
                    underlayColor="transparent"
                >
                    <Text>Hide</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                <Animated.View style={{height: this.state.height}}>
                    <Text>Content</Text>
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.state.height` isn't being used anywhere in the code you posted. please post a minimal verifiable example

Comment: @FuzzyTree sorry about that, didnt notice. I fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the animation appears to 'blink' is because you're using a spring animation which recoils or bounces once it reaches its final value. Try replacing `spring` with `timing` to get rid of the bounce:

```
showContent = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.height, {toValue:130}).start();
}

hideContent = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.height, {toValue:0}).start();
}
```

Comment: This just saved me a lot of time. This is a hard problem to Google. Is there anyway to reducer the recoil so it acts norma, or are there just certain properties for which spring does not work?

Comment: Answered my own question. Seems to be related to the `bounciness` property. Go figure, right?

Comment: Strike that, I was only half-right. There can still be some blinking with a `bounciness` of 0 and a high `speed` value. Is there an article or document describing when to use certain animations for certain properties?

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into the same issue. You can still use Animated.spring but it needs the correct min height for the extra "wiggle room". Seems it may vary, in my case it was a min height 2 for a max height of 55.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late, but I had this issue and solved by just using the config `bounciness: 0` to disable the blink completely.

You can find more info about [in the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#spring).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 6.5 years old but I had this problem right now and because its the first questions that pops out on google when searched I'll tell you what fixed it for me.

So this is my animation:

```
const progressBarAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(progressBarValue).current

useEffect(() => {
    Animated.spring(progressBarAnimation, {
      toValue: progressBarValue(),
      speed: 10,
      bounciness: 10,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start()
  }, [progressBarValue])
```

And I fixed it by using intrapolate and using the `extrapolate: 'clamp'` value:

```
const animatedWidth = progressBarAnimation.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: ['0%', '100%'],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  })
```

And use it like this:

```
<Animated.View style={{ width: animatedWidth }}/>
```

Without `extrapolate: 'clamp'`, when my progress bar would reach 0 it would fill up to 100% and back to 0% 2 or 3 times.